# How can I solve this error from TIFF file?

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, google-colab

I used google colab(python) to read a tif file with Tiff file. But it shows:

> TiffPage 0: <COMPRESSION.LZW: 5> requires the 'imagecodecs' package.

This is my code:

```
!pip install tifffile 
!pip install imagecodecs 
import numpy 
import tifffile as tiff 
img = tiff.imread('/content/gdrive/My Drive/My Driver/imageToDriveExample.tif') 
matrix = img[:,:,:] 
print(matrix)
```

Answer (score 11):

You should do below:

```
pip install imagecodecs
```

You will be able to use tifffile without error after tart.

Answer (score 2):

You could use GDAL, it's installed by default in colab:

```
import gdal
array = gdal.Open('/content/gdrive/My Drive/My Driver/imageToDriveExample.tif').ReadAsArray()
```

Answer (score 2):

Or use this:

```
!pip install rasterio 

import rasterio as rio

import numpy as np

with rio.open("file path") as img :

    imgnp= img.read()

    imgmeta=img.meta
```